# jquery div won't show/hide slide

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to show a div and slide in from the right when textbox gets focus and hide the div and slide out when the textbox loses focus.  I had it working before and then it stopped working.  `Please have a look at this jsfiddle:`

https://jsfiddle.net/tekknow/8qj99bkt/1/

The div is shown initially when it should be hidden.

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me when I add jQuery and jQuery UI to the fiddle ? -> **https://jsfiddle.net/8qj99bkt/3/**

Comment: where did you add jQuery UI?  All I see is jquery.js in external resources

Comment: I added it in the dropdown menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#pwd').focus(function() {
        $('#rules').show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
   });

    $('#pwd').blur(function() {

        $('#rules').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);

   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8qj99bkt/5/

The following changes were made:

- Replaced focusout event with blur (optional).
- Added JQueryUI reference.
- Re-added JQUERY reference.

You are just missing [JQuery-ui](https://jqueryui.com/) reference.

Comment: Ah, ok, Could I ask you one more thing?  In my real code, I don't want to have a top and left attribute.  I want it to just be dependent on the position of the text box.  So I changed display to inline-block and added a hide() to the js.  But now it slides underneath the text box instead of to the right.

Comment: Never mind.  It's working now.  Thank you very much!  https://jsfiddle.net/tekknow/8qj99bkt/12/